# Service not running when hosted in IIS 7

Tags: wcf, iis-7

I have  a wcf service which has been hosted in IIS 7 . I made WCF service in visual studio 2008
I am following the below 2 procedures

Procedure-1

```
1- Run visual-studio 2008 as administartor
2-Run the service application .
3- Lets say the url is "http://Myhost:57232/Service1.svc"
4-Open visual studio 2008 command prompt 
5-type wcftestclient.exe http://Myhost:57232/Service1.svc" 
6-All the function works fine .
```

Procedure - 2

```
1- Host the service in IIS 7
2-Browse the site 
3-Get the url lets say http://MyMachinename/test_Biku/Service1.svc?wsdl
4-Open visual studio 2008 command prompt 
5-type wcftestclient.exe http://MyMachinename/test_Biku/Service1.svc?wsdl
6-not even a single function  .
```

Procedure -2 fails but procedure 1 does not .

Can anyone please tell me what is going wrong ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: What happens if you open http: //MyMachinename/test_Biku/Service1.svc?wsdl in your browser? Does it produce a valid wsdl, or do you get errors?

Comment: @nvoigt yes it gives a valid wsdl ..

Comment: In Step 5, you once give the .svc and once the full wsdl link. Try the other way round?

Comment: @nvoigt try that too . But still the same result .
I think i have to do some changes in IIS hosting something related to authentication because dlls being used by service use sql server authentication .